# Position of a rotating sprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am rotating a sprite using the following code but I am having a hard time finding the position of the sprite during its rotation. I can find the position around which the sprite rotates but not its current position.

```
[item convertToWorldSpace:CGPointZero];  
[item setPosition:ccp(375,160)];         
id rotate = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:3 angle:360];  
[item runAction: [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction: [CCSequence actions: rotate,nil]]];
```

Comment: The sprites position is the position around which it rotates. I take it you have moved it away from this point using anchorpoint?

Comment: Exactly. I used the anchorpoint to move the sprite away from the defined position of the sprite. As a result the postion does not actually represent the location of the rotating sprite. So how do I find it's actual location?

Comment: tip: don't modify anchorpoint. You can achieve the same effect by adding a ccnode and adding your sprite to it, then offset the sprite. By rotating the node instead of the sprite you get the same effect as rotating the sprite with modified anchorPoint. You then have both the node's and the sprite's rotated position.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to change position of your sprite. All transformations (rotation, scale, etc.) are proceed relatively to anchorPoint of your node. If you want your sprite to stay in the same position visually, just set anchorPoint to

```
ccp(0.5f, 0.5f)
```

By the way, the CCSprite has such anchorPoint by default.

During ALL of your transformations anchorPoint of your node will have position that you set to this node. So, if you set anchorPoint to

```
ccp(0.f, 0.f)
```

the left-down corner of your sprite will be at the same position during rotation, scaling, etc.

Also you should remember, that your own subclasses of CCNode (not of CCSprite) will not react to anchorPoint property, until you set instance's property isRelativeToAnchorPoint to YES.

```
[yourNode setIsRelativeAnchorPoint:YES];
```

Comment: This simply doesn't answer the question. The user asks how they can find the position of the sprite taking into account its transform as affected by the anchorpoint/

Comment: i tried to explain how to use anchorpoints. his problem is misunderstanding of what is anchorPoint

Comment: I stand by my vote. This would be a good supplement to an answer, but I maintain that you haven't actually answered the question.